# including a condition dynamically based on another condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query as below

```
select --------
from table a
left outer join ....c
where 
(a.column='123') and (c.column='456')
```

I would like to

> include "(c.column='456')" only when (a.column='123') is not null

how do I do that in a single query ? or do I need to write two separate queries ?

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: rdbms I am using is oracle

Comment: is a.column nullable?

Comment: Sorry but even with your latest (3rd) version of the question, its unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straightforward :

```
select --------
from table
left outer join....
where (Condition A IS NULL) OR (condition A AND condition B)
```

UPDATED: For your conditions:

```
where (a.column is null) or (a.column='123' and c.column='456')
```

It will include a a row if it's `a.column` is null or if bot `a.column` and `c.column` have valid values.

Comment: My two conditions are like (a.column='123') and (c.column='456')

Comment: my query is not having only these two conditions but having other conditions as well

Comment: Updated answer for your condition. Same should apply for others.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your requirement this is the sql you want

```
select distinct cm.credit_amt,e.credit_lifetime,e.credit_desc,e.icom_code,e.entry_hint,
                e.credit_id,e.credit_type_id,e.recontract_period,a.class_desc,a.offer_id,
                a.offer_class_id 
from rti_retention.package a 
left outer join rti_retention.offer_class_credit b on (a.offer_id=b.offer_id 
                                                       and a.offer_class_id=b.offer_class_id 
                                                       and a.customer_type_id=b.customer_type_id) 
left outer join rti_retention.credit_pre_bundle c on (b.credit_id=c.credit_id) 
left outer join rti_retention.credit e on (c.credit_id=e.credit_id) 
left outer join rti_retention.credit_mix_amount cm on (cm.credit_id=c.credit_id and cm.prod_mix_id=a.prod_mix_id)
where a.offer_class_id not in (1,2,16)
and a.channel_id=5 and a.customer_type_id=1 
and a.offer_id='6055' 
and c.prod_mix_id = case when (select count(*) 
                               from rti_retention.credit_pre_bundle c1 
                               where c1.prod_mix_id='1000' ) > 1 then '1000' else c.prod_mix_id end
and e.icom_code is not null
```

some time there will be some sql syntax errors. due to i havent full data base i wrote sql on mind. cant test it.

Comment: THanks for the response...I was wrong in my requirement...sorry